# Passing a Javascript variable to C# code in <script> section

Tags: javascript, c#, variables

```
var code = $('#hastane').val();

var url = '@Url.Action("HataIstatistikleriExcel", "Reports", new
{
  baslangicDonem = Model.BaslangicDonem,
  bitisDonem = Model.BitisDonem,
  hospitalCode = code
})';
window.open(url);
```

I can't pass code variable to Url.Action... "It shows cannot resolve code"

Comment: Please post syntactically-correct code. The above is at best cut short.

Comment: you forgot a '}' symbol before window.open(url)

Comment: @AlexandruMihai: At the very least, but I think there's rather more missing there.

Comment: you can use ajax and give parameters to url..it is more easily

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see why your question as it stands is not a good fit at SO and is voted down. HINT: give more details, like actual result and expected result "Cannot resolve code" is not helpful. At least show the verbatim error message

Comment: If I edit my code will you delete negative points?

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to solve it by adding a placeholder in MVC built URL then replace that value dynamically using javascript while click event is triggered as shown below.

```
    $("#expHastaneAna").click(function () {

        var code = 'dynamicCode';

        var url = '@Url.Action("HataIstatistikleriExcel", "Reports", new
        {
            baslangicDonem = Model.BaslangicDonem,
            bitisDonem = Model.BitisDonem,
            hospitalCode = "{0}"
        })';

        url = decodeURI(url);
        url = url.replace("{0}", code);
        url = decodeURI(url);
        console.log(url);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This code is working correctly. :)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot directly access Server side variable in JavaScript. First you have to assign it's value to hidden field and then get value from that hidden field in JavaScript.

Comment: Which is true other than that there are lots of better options than a hidden field. But it has nothing to do with the question, which is *going the other way*.